# What are alternatives to cash deposits, if you need short term liquidity above the FDIC insured limit?

Tags: united-states, bankruptcy, fdic, deposit-insurance

Could you, for example, invest everyting into Bonds or ETFs? Are they safe in case the bank goes bankrupt? Are they liquid enough? What is the timeframe to convert these alternatives to cash? Minutes, hours, days?

Comment: OMG, would people **give it a rest** about "OMG banks aren't safe now, where do I keep my money?" That is utterly foolish. You know, there was a *Great Depression* starting in 1929, and the USA learned a whole ton of lessons about how to manage banks. When it happened again in 2009, those lessons actually worked - hundreds of banks folded and nobody lost any money - not even over $250k holders and not taxpayers either. FDIC payout was $0.  Everything worked.  *To now say* everything is broken is idiotic.

Answer (score 1):

Timeframe to convert most market investments to cash is days.

Most crises which can't wait that long can be put on a business's line of credit or credit card. Most transactions these days aren't in cash anyway.

If you're really concerned about needing hard funds immediately at the same moment a bank is going under, split your operating capital between two banks.